# drupal image path

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

i created a page content type, and put this code in it. and set the input style to php.why the image can't show. i test it on my localhost.

```
       <img src="<?php echo $bath_path; ?>/images/1.jpg">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal way:

```
$path2file = base_path().'/images/1.jpg'; // If image located in {drupal root}/images. If image located in files directory, use file_directory_path() to get this path
print theme('image', $path_to_file, t('Image altername name'), t('Image title'));
```

Comment: thank you.got it.but i still don't know when i shoud use  base_path(), when i should use $base_path. which is better?
print theme('image', $path_to_file, t('Image altername name'), t('Image title')); what's this line meaning? thank you

Comment: `base_path()` will always work, but in some templates, the return value of `base_path()` has been stored in the `$base_path` variable (I'm not sure why, for performance reasons perhaps). The line `print theme('image', [arguments]);` means that you're calling the theme() function and printing its output. The theme() function in its turn will call `theme_image([arguments])`, or if `theme_image()` has been overridden, the overriding function will be called. To learn more about the Drupal theming system and theme overrides, see http://drupal.org/node/341628.