# Drupal images in page.tpl.php

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming

I am new to Drupal and Bootstrap, and I am trying to add images along with text and stuff onto the body of my site.

We've been modifying the page.tpl.php file in filenamehere > docroot > sites> all > themes > subtheme_bootstrap > templates to change the body of the site. All HTML that we have used in the page.tpl.php site works, EXCEPT adding images.

To add images, we used the html tag `<img src="link" alt="lol />` in the page.tpl.php file, like below:

```
<div class = "container-fluid">
    <div class = "jumbotron bodygrey">
      <img src="../images/benefits_orange.png" alt="picture" width="300" height="320">
    </div>
</div>
```

However, while the frame of the image with the correct width and height along with the alt caption is showing, the image itself does not show. I've also tried adding a link from a website incase I was putting in the wrong directory, but the same thing happens. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: When you inspect the image (*Developer Tools*), does it show up? I'm betting on an incorrect path.

Comment: Yes, it does. I also tried adding in a link from a website as the img src in case that was the problem, but the image also does not show up.

Comment: That's really weird then! What does the directory structure look like?

Comment: The image file is docroot > sites > all > themes > subtheme_bootstrap > images > benefits_orange.png. The php file is docroot > sites > all > themes > subtheme_bootstrap > templates > page.tpl.php

Comment: You can't use a relative path to an image that's displayed on various pages (URLs). You must use an absolute path in your HTML img tag.

Use something like `<?php echo theme('image', array('path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'subtheme_bootstrap') .'/images/benefits_orange.png')); ?>`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151618/drupal-image-path

Answer (score 2):

Use `$directory` variable in the image path. It points to the current theme directory:

```
  <img src="<?php print $directory ?>/images/benefits_orange.png" alt="picture" width="300" height="320">
```

Easy J

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, you can't use a relative path in your `page.tpl.php`, only in CSS, because when the HTML gets rendered, it tried to find that image starting from the root of your site. Instead, you can use the Drupal `theme("image")` function like so:

```
<?php echo theme('image', array('path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'subtheme_bootstrap') .'/images/benefits_orange.png')); ?>
```

which will translate to something like: 
`/sites/all/themes/subtheme_bootstrap/images/benefits_orange.png`